# Burn polygons into DEM raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, dem

I am trying to take a Digital Elevation Model raster layer and “burn” polygons into it, so that they show up in the DEM layer. I know there are methods for burning streams/rivers into raster DEMs, but these would be lines, and I am not sure about polygons.

I have the following DEM layer with Reservoir polygons overlaid :
[image]

I want to take my reservoir polygons and “burn” them into the DEM layer so that they become a part of the raster layer.
Can this easily be done in QGIS?

Comment: Do you have depth value of the reservoir, or do you have desired end elevation for the reservoir area?

Comment: I have area of inundation of reservoirs and reservoir volume.

Comment: then I can get depth bolue of the reservoir. so what should I do next?

Comment: What is currently in the area where the polygon is. Is it flat? i.e. lake surface elevation?

Comment: The area has a highest elevation of 114 m and the lowest elevation of 76 m

Comment: while the height of the dam is 34 m with a peak elevation of 98 m.

Comment: The rasterize tool in the processing toolbox can rasterize also polygons. I suppose it is using internally gdal_rasterize https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html. Just select your burn value to match with the desired color in your palette.

Comment: As mentioned by others just above, you just need to burn the DEM with one relevant and single elevation (if what you want to burn is the lake surface). Then, apart for the dam part, the appropriate elevation corresponds to the DEM height value on the polygon contours (you should get a similar DEM height value along these contours as by definition this polygon mostly corresponds to the terrain contour line)

Answer (score 1):

Rasterize will do this.

Add the elevation value that you want to burn in to the DTM to your polygons attribute table. Run rasterize on your polygon using the value you just added into the attribute table. Select your actual DTM as the output, not a new file. You'll get the polygon 'burned' into the original DTM.

(please save a copy of your DTM first).